# ulimit -s on Netbeans 8.0.2

Tags: linux, netbeans, ulimit

I want to run a C program in NetBeans 8.0.2 (on Xubuntu 14.04) with `ulimit -s` set. I've already tried on *Re-run with arguments* writing `ulimit -s 2048; "${OUTPUT_PATH}"`, but it shows me this error:

```
/bin/sh: 1: exec: ulimit: not found
```

I don't want to compile the program on my own in order to set ulimit on the terminal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't look like a C question.

Anyway, on Linux, `ulimit`is *not* a system command, it's a bash builtin. Unless `/bin/sh` is linked to bash (which it is usually not) the command won't be known to the shell.

try `/bin/bash -c ulimit -s 2048` instead.

Note that this new limit will only be active in this particular shell - once you return from it, you'll see whatever you had before.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I tried what you said but it displays:`unlimited` and it doesn't execute the program

Comment: It does. You probably just don't see the result.

Try "`/bin/bash -c "ulimit -s 2048; ulimit -s"`"

This will show you that the limit has been set (as I explained above, only in the shell you just called).

Comment: I forgot to mention I'm running this program on the internal emulator of NetBeans. Maybe is this the problem?

Comment: make sure your executable really runs within the limits you set.

`/bin/bash -c "ulimit -s 2048; <your program>"`

might do the trick.